# Is there an absence limit to withdraw the British citizenship from a person born there?

Tags: citizenship, england-and-wales, nationality

There is a case where a person born in england and held the UK citizenship but at the age of 7 he/she left the UK along with her family into another country and never entered the UK for almost 12 years is he/she still considered as a **british citizent** or he/she have to go throuhg the process of getting a new citizenship

Is there an absence limit to withdraw the British citizenship from a person born there?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen also look at questions on Expatriates.SE (but they mostly point to the gov.uk questionnaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  One cannot lose British citizenship simply for being absent from the UK.  It's only possible to withdraw someone's British citizenship if their presence in Britain is found to be "not conducive to the public good," or if they obtained it by fraud.  See https://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/2016/06/21/citizenship-stripping-new-figures-reveal-theresa-may-deprived-33-individuals-british-citizenship/.

Comment: I'm going to the embassy next week and will verify with them ! Thanks 

Comment: @JasonVanHil If you have verified with the embassy, it might help others if you post a comment or your own answer to confirm.

Comment: Basically they told me that there is no way to withdraw the british citizenship from any one only if there is a reason or something to prove that he is engaged on something dangerous like terrorism.

Comment: I think "if obtained by fraud" doesn't actually mean you _lose_ your British citizenship, it means that you _never actually had_ British citizenship, and authorities only just figured this out.

Comment: @gnasher729 that isn't obvious from the [nationality act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61/section/40).  The US stresses the nullity of a fraudulent naturalization because its courts have found that it is unable to revoke the citizenship of its citizens against their will.  Since the UK *can* do so, it doesn't need to maintain the technical distinction between deprivation and finding that the naturalization was void.